# Screen recording 3d zoom

Tags: effects

I want to record screen and add some zoom effects like in this video: https://vimeo.com/59343034 (for example at 00:11)
Can you tell me, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very simple perspective shift or 3d transform of a video layer.  It can be fairly easily accomplished in any decent non-linear video editor or trivially in After Effects.

You simply have to scale the video to fill the frame and then apply a perspective distortion to it to make it appear to be off angle from the "camera".

Alternately, a 3d layer can be used in After Effects and the plane the video is being played back on can actually be moved closer to the camera and rotated.

Comment: But if I do this with normal screen record, will it be good quality?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine with a normal screen recording as long as you are using a decent resolution for things.  That is how that type of thing is traditionally done.